# Can't make label receive string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

**EDIT:**

I Have a textfield, a button and a label in a view and a label on the other view, they are controlled by **different** viewControllers, in my code I take the float value of the textfield and transform it into a string, then I put this string into the two labels. But the problem is, only the label on the view with the textfield and the button receive it, the other label, that is on the other view, don't receive anything!

first.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NotasFirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tfield;
- (IBAction)calcular:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clicarFora:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tirarteclado:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *valorstr;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mostradordeteste;
@end
```

first.m

```
#import "NotasFirstViewController.h"
#import "NotasSecondViewController.h"

@interface NotasFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation NotasFirstViewController
@synthesize valorstr;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)calcular:(id)sender {

    float valor = [_tfield.text floatValue];
    NSString *valorstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", valor];
    NSLog(@"%.2f", valor);
    NSLog(valorstr);
    _mostradordeteste.text = valorstr;
    NotasSecondViewController *second = [[NotasSecondViewController alloc] init];

}

-(IBAction)clicarFora:(id)sender{

    [_tfield resignFirstResponder];

}
-(IBAction)tirarteclado:(id)sender{

    [sender resignFirstResponder];

}


@end
```

second.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NotasSecondViewController : UIViewController{

    NSString *valorclasstwo;
    IBOutlet UILabel *classe2labelvalor;

}

@end
```

second.m

```
#import "NotasSecondViewController.h"
#import "NotasFirstViewController.h"

@interface NotasSecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation NotasSecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)teste{

    NotasFirstViewController *n1 = [[NotasFirstViewController alloc] init];
    valorclasstwo = [n1 valorstr];
    classe2labelvalor.text = valorclasstwo;
}

@end
```

[image: conectionsfirst]

[image: conectionssecond]

Comment: Did you check to make sure that your label is connected in the xib?  (NSLog the label object, and also the label's text value after setting it, to be sure that the label "exists" and you're getting the value set correctly.)

Comment: Maybe.. the other view.. "Needs Refresh"

Comment: make sure you are applying property on text of UILabel not on UILabel.

Comment: Can you post screen shots of your viewController and your connections?

Answer (score 0):

Look if the outleds of both labels are correctly connected (black circle). if the circles are not filled, then something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check the binding of your Label in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

First of all Check Your outlet is set to label is proper or not. If it is ok then first give value of label using XIB and check one static value is coming. if value you are getting right value then there is issue while passing value from one view controller to another. Make sure you have created `property` in proper manner.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strLabel;
```

and then`@synthesize` it properly in .m file. If you have done this thing then debug your code and pass the value to this view controller.

One more thing set your value from first view controller like this way.

```
WebLinkViewController *sampleView = [[WebLinkViewController alloc] init] ;
sampleView.stringTitle = strTitle;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
```

if you will do in this manner you will get value in another view controller also, You need to debug your code using `breakpoint`. Hope this will help you.